# How do I remove instances of classes that do not match a dropdown value using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to implement filtering on my page using a dropdown, and the removal of classes that do not match the drop down selection by comparing items using a loop. However, when I execute the code, a seemingly random selection of items get removed. Maybe it's not random, but I can't figure out how the removed items are being selected. I'm sure there's something wrong with the way I wrote the code, but I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong.

When I log the variables to the console, they appear as expected.

```
const filter = document.querySelector('.mainFilter');

if (filter) {
  var testing = document.getElementsByClassName('bigMomma');
  var testing2 = testing[0].getElementsByClassName('innerArticle');
  console.log(testing2[1].className);
  filter.addEventListener('change', () => {
    var filterValue = filter.value;
    var classNameCompare = `innerArticle ${filterValue}`;
    console.log(classNameCompare);
    for (let i = 0; i < testing2.length; i++) {
      if (testing2[i].className === classNameCompare) {
        console.log(`All good.`);
      } else {
        testing2[i].remove();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an unintuitive *live* collection which contains all elements in the document that match the class *at that instant* that the collection is examined. So if you `.remove()` one of the classes from the DOM *while you're iterating over the collection*, the collection's indicies will rearrange themselves to fill in the hole created by the removed element. For example:

```js
const coll = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

As you can see above, the 2nd element still exists in the DOM because when the 1st was removed, the indicies rearranged themselves, so on the next iteration, when `i` was 1, the loop stopped.

Easiest solution is to use `querySelectorAll` instead, which returns a *static* NodeList that won't mutate itself while you're iterating over it. Change:

```
var testing = document.getElementsByClassName('bigMomma');
var testing2 = testing[0].getElementsByClassName('innerArticle');
```

to

```
const innerArticles = document.querySelectorAll('.bigMomma .innerArticle');
```

and then reference `innerArticles` and `.remove()` elements of it when needed.

Comment: This works as expected, thank you! I learned something new today. One question... is there a way to preserve the original “innerArticles” content, so that the drop down filter can be used more than one time?

Comment: You could keep the elements in the DOM and just hide them instead: change `.remove()` to `.style.display = 'none'`, and then remove the `display` property when you want to display them all again.